# count binary roots of an integer (java)

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been trying to find the right solution for the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465519/binary-roots-of-an-integer)  but in Java, and slightly modified since the count is supposed to be returned.

I came up with the following solution:

```
public static int count(int n) {
    // check for 0 or smaller
    if (n <= 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    // find root of N
    int root = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(n));
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < root; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            // calculate bit_rev(i)
            int reverse = bit_rev(i);

            // calculate bit_rev(N/i)
            int reverseDiv = bit_rev((int)Math.floor(n/i));

            // check whether i * bit_rev(i) == N or i == bit_rev(N/i)
            if (reverse*i == n
                    || i == reverseDiv) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Found reverse (N = %d, i = %d, bit_rev(i) = %d, bit_rev(i) * i = %d, bit_rev(N/i) = %d)", n, i, reverse, reverse*i, reverseDiv));
                count++;
            } else {
                System.out.println(String.format("N = %d mod i = %d == 0, but no match (bit_rev(i) = %d, bit_rev(i) * i = %d, bit_rev(N/i) = %d)", n, i, reverse, reverse*i, reverseDiv));
            }
        }
    }


    if (count == 0) {
        // didn't match -> return -1
        return -1;
    } else {
        // return whatever the count was
        return count;
    }
}

public static int bit_rev(int n) {
    String string = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    String reverseString = new StringBuffer(string).reverse().toString();
    int reverse = Integer.parseInt(reverseString, 2);
    return reverse;
}
```

In the reference sample the solution for N = 3245 is supposed to be count = 55.

However, my solution finds that `count = 1 (i = 55, bit_rev(i) = 59).`

The other reference samples were:

```
-) N = 50 -> count = 1
-) N = 286 -> count = 2
```

I understand that the solution for finding bit_rev() isn't the greatest (most efficient one), but I don't think it's wrong, is it?

Is there any other mistake in here, or is the reference sample for N = 3245 wrong?

Comment: Would you explain me this line `if (n % i == 0)`? Why the binary root will satisfy this condition?

Comment: We're looking for binary roots = integers. If n/i is no "clean division", you can disqualify i right away. E.g. i=7 can't be a binary root of n=50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misread the question, or the reference answer is wrong. If it's anything like the question at http://algorithmsforever.blogspot.com/2011/12/integer-binary-roots.html?m=1 then you need to be returning the smallest binary root, not the number of binary roots.

Regardless, I think your implementation is correctly working them out. 55 is indeed the smallest binary root of 3245 (not the count of roots).

Comment: Thanks, but it was definitely about counting it (the original method name was emphasizing this even more) and as you see, the other two reference examples are also counts, and not the min. I'm pretty sure now they adjusted the question from min -> count and forgot to adjust the result accordingly.